# select2 display not updating label text but value is changing

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using **select2 v4.0.3** along with JQuery.
I initialize my selectors as:

```
$("#datatype").select2({
        theme: "classic"
        }); 

 $("#unit").select2({
        theme: "classic"
        });
```

Then I want to detect a change on `#datatype` and change the value of `#unit` which I do as follows:

```
$("#datatype").on('select2:select',function () {
    $("#unit").val('21'); //udpate unit type to be 'none'
    });
```

The problem is that the value of `#unit` is getting set to 21 but the displayed label for that selector is not updating. Any suggestions ?

It seems as if select2 is not aware of the event or that it has not been setup properly to listen to changes. I am not sure what the solution is. I am new to web technologies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After digging through the Select2 documentation, any `.val()` updates need to be followed by  `$('#unit').trigger('change');`

So in my case, the code should look like

```
$("#datatype").on('select2:select',function () {
    $('#unit').val('21'); // Select the option with a value of '21'
    $('#unit').trigger('change'); // Notify any JS components that the value changed
});
```

Note that this is only true for select2 version 4 and greater.

I would also recommend people upgrade to version 4 since you can make direct calls to change values without having to specify `initSelect()`

Answer (score 8):

Using select2 v4.0 you can also trigger the `change.select2` event to update the displayed label. This prevents other components that are listening to the change event from causing side effects.

```
$("#datatype").on('select2:select',function () {
    $('#unit').val('21'); // Select the option with a value of '21'
    $('#unit').trigger('change.select2'); // Notify only Select2 of changes
});
```